# How to set parent attribute based on child attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, callback

I have a situation where a parent `Order` has multiple child `Items`. Both `Order` and `Item` have a `status_id` column. I want the user to update the `status_id` of the `Item`, and then when all of the `Items` have a `status_id`, then the `Order's status_id` should be auto-set (to some value based on what `Item status_ids` are).

The code that I currently have is this:

```
class Item
  after_save :set_order_status_id

  def set_order_status_id
    if self.order.items.where(status_id:nil).blank?
       self.order.update_attributes(status_id:X)
    end
  end
end
```

Ths is pretty smelly code because it violates SRP, uses a callback, and is pretty inefficient, considering that this means if an `Order` has 5 `Items` and all 5 `Items` are being updated, after EACH `Item` update, the `set_order_status_id` method is called, and a database query is run.

So... is there a better way of writing this to avoid these issues? Particularly I'm interested in removing the inefficiency with constantly checking the parent `Order's` other child `Items'` statuses... because again if an all 5 `Items` is updated at once, it's silly to check after each and every update when it should just wait until the 5th update.... Does Rails have a magical way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is no, there is no magic way to do that using the framework. Your best option is to use a customised solution and run your check only after your items update. Something like:

```
 ...your code...
 order.items.update_all(whatever) <-- update items
 update_status(order) <-- update order status
 ...

 def update_status(order)       
   return if order.items.where(status_id: nil).exist? <-- more efficient
   update_attributes(status_id: X) 
 end
```

the method could also be in the Offer model for simplicity.

Answer (score 0):

If the order status can be derived from the item status at any point in time, it may be better to avoid setting it in the database entirely. You can instead create an accessor to query it on-demand:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  def status
    # memoize the calculation, including nils
    return @status if defined? @status

    item_statuses = items.pluck(:status).uniq
    # your logic here:
    # 1. check for any nils
    # 2. check for any 'pending', etc.
    @status = 'pending'
  end
end
```

Whether this alternate solution fits your needs depends on your database read patterns.